Power Automate Email Action - Body won't stay in code view after Saving
I have a flow that sends an email with a logo at the top of the email body.  In order to have it display in the email body, I need the Send an Email 2 action to be in Code view.  Each time I change it to code view and save, it always reverts back to the normal view - so the logo won't display.  Does anyone know why it won't "stick" after saving?
Thanks

Have you ever found a solution for this?

I never did.  There are certain flows that when I open them in Edit mode, as long as I don't open any Send an Email actions, it'll stay in code view.  But the moment I expand one of those actions, I have to delete the text, convert to code view again, apply the href, etc.  It's annoying.
